# Why is Intent Extra NULL after back button pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-livedata

***The Problem***

I have a main activity 'HomeActivity` which is a calendar.

When you click on a cell you are taken to the next activity `WorkoutButtonsActivity`.

Data from the first activity is passed to the second where it is used in a method to workout the dates for the week (MON - SUN) for the selected cell.

The problem I am having is that when I go from `WorkoutButtonsActivity` to the next activity (`ExerciseListViewActivity` ) and then click the back button in the menuBar, one of the intents I pass `EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES` is null.

However, when I press the default android back button (on the bottom of the emulator, this problem does not occur.

Moreover, when I press the menu back button on my physical Huawei device, it works perfectly fine.
In other words I am only getting this issue in my emulator.

The error message I am getting is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List java.util.ArrayList.subList(int, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.exerciseappv5.WorkoutButtonsActivity.onCreate(WorkoutButtonsActivity.java:83)
```

***What I have tried***

I have done some research as to how to avoid this and a few people suggested to add:

`android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my manifest file which I have done, however the error still occurs.

I have also thought about overriding the `onBackPressed` and passing the intent backwards however I feel this is unnecessary.

**Question**

Why is this specific intent extra null and how can I avoid the error message and get the code working?

**Relevant Code**

1. Method I am using in activity 1 (calendar) to navigate to activity 2 (WorkoutButtonsActivity)

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                final String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));
                final ArrayList<String> arrayListDateFormattedList = (ArrayList<String>) datesFormattedList;

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WorkoutButtonsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_DATE, date);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES, arrayListDateFormattedList);

                getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

2. `WorkoutButtonsActivity` (Relevant code only)

```
public class WorkoutButtonsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.workout_list);

                getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_DATE)) {
                    SELECTED_DATE = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATE);
                }

                setTitle(SELECTED_DATE);

                if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES)) {

            EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES);

            if (SELECTED_DATE != null && !SELECTED_DATE.isEmpty()) {
                index_number = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.indexOf(SELECTED_DATE) + 1;
            }
        }

        //There is no EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS
        // we need to get EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES WORKING HERE...


        if ((index_number / 7) <= 1) {                                 
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(0, 7);
        } else if ((index_number / 7) <= 2) {                              // Crash happens here
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(7, 14);
        } else if ((index_number / 7) <= 3) {
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(14, 21);
        } else if ((index_number / 7) <= 4) {
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(21, 28);
        } else if ((index_number / 7) <= 5) {
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(28, 35);
        } else {
            thisWeeksDates = EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS.subList(35, 42);
        }

       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                openExerciseViewActivity();           
        }
    }

    public void openExerciseViewActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExercisesListViewActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(ExercisesListViewActivity.CHOSEN_DATE, SELECTED_DATE);
        intent.putExtra(ExercisesListViewActivity.WORKOUT_ID, buttonClicked);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra(ExercisesListViewActivity.EXTRA_WEEK_DATES, (ArrayList<String>) thisWeeksDatesCopy);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

3. `ExerciseListViewActivity`

```
public class ExercisesListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            current_date = extras.getString(CHOSEN_DATE, "TODAY");
            setTitle(current_date);
            THIS_WEEK_DATES = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_WEEK_DATES);
        }

        if (intent.hasExtra(WORKOUT_ID)) {
            currentWorkoutID = (intent.getIntExtra(WORKOUT_ID, -1));
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.exerciseHistoryRV);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final ExerciseAndGoalAdapter adapter = new ExerciseAndGoalAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        junctionViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(JunctionViewModel.class);

        junctionViewModel.getAllWorkoutExercises(currentWorkoutID, THIS_WEEK_DATES).observe(this, new Observer<List<ExerciseAndGoal>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ExerciseAndGoal> exercises) {
                adapter.setExercises(exercises);
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExerciseAndGoalAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(ExerciseAndGoal exercises) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(ExercisesListViewActivity.this, RecordExerciseActivity2.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra(RecordExerciseActivity2.PARENT_EXERCISE_ID, Integer.toString(exercises.getExercises_id()));
                intent.putExtra(RecordExerciseActivity2.EXTRA_DATE, getTitle());
                intent.putExtra(RecordExerciseActivity2.EXTRA_JUNCTIONID, exercises.getJunction_id());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra(RecordExerciseActivity2.EXTRA_WEEK_DATES, (ArrayList<String>) THIS_WEEK_DATES);

                startActivityForResult(intent, RECORD_EXERCISE_REQUEST);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It possible that the simulator destroys, restarts the WorkoutButtonsActivity without the intent bundle when you use the nav back button. Try to use onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState to save, restore the bundle.
add this method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayListExtra(RecordExerciseActivity2.EXTRA_WEEK_DATES, (ArrayList<String>) THIS_WEEK_DATES);
}
```

in onCreate, after this line

```
EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES);
```

add:

```
if(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS == null && savedInstanceState != null){
    EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATESS = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES);
 }
```

Comment: How would I do this in my scenario? I have had a look online and I am unsure of how to correctly implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using putStringArrayListExtra() instead of putExtra()

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WorkoutButtonsActivity.class);
       i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_DATE, date);
       i.putStringArrayListExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_VISIBLE_DATES, arrayListDateFormattedList);
```

Comment: The problem still occurs after implementing this.